# How to Retrieve all links from a dynamic website with selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, json, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have the following code:

```
rom selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

prefs = {'profile.managed_default_content_settings.images':2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options) 
driver.get("http://biggestbook.com/ui/catalog.html#/search?cr=1&rs=12&st=BM&category=1")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ess-product-brand + [href]")))
results = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in links]
#print(links)
print(results)
driver.quit()
```

I however, only get the results/links for the featured products and not all the products. Sometimes, (very rarely) if I run it a 20 times I get all the products. But I want to always be able to get all the products. I also tried a different method below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options) 
driver.get("http://biggestbook.com/ui/catalog.html#/search?cr=1&rs=12&st=BM&category=1")

links = [elem.get_attribute("href") for elem in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')]

print(links)
```

Same problem. 
My question is, what is it that I am missing that I cannot get all the links? This has been driving me crazy for 2 weeks now. I also tried to delay the timer thinking it might not be loading but it still didn't work. Thanks

Comment: Which all products? Are you looking at `Kitchen Roll Towels, Perforated, 2-Ply, 11 x 8, White, 85 Sheets/Roll, 30 Rls/Ct`, `Pathways Soak-Proof Shield Mediumweight Paper Plates, 8 1/2", Grn/Burg, 125/Pk`, etc?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. Those are the test cases. However, I mostly only get the featured ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a control total by extracting the results count total and adding the featured total to it. Those numbers are already available to you so you can loop until #hrefs meets this. You probably want to add a time out to the loop.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

prefs = {'profile.managed_default_content_settings.images':2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options) 
driver.get("http://biggestbook.com/ui/catalog.html#/search?cr=1&rs=12&st=BM&category=1")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
nonFeaturedTotal = int(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR , '.ess-view-item-count-text'))).text.split(' ')[-1])
featuredTotal = len(wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ess-product-container-featured"))))
expectedTotal = featuredTotal + nonFeaturedTotal

while False:
    len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ess-product-brand + [href]")) == expectedTotal

links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ess-product-brand + [href]")
results = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in links]

print(len(results))
print(links)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks man. Seems to work but sometimes it still gives only featured. Nonetheless, ill spend time understanding this. Thanks!

Comment: I’ll have a look again tonight

Comment: is there a way to do multiple retries automatically without closing session?

Comment: You could use try catch. I haven’t looked at whether selenium itself offers a back off retry. Documentation might detail this if available.

Comment: Hey, based on the code you corrected above for links, I tried to make one for tables but I couldn't get it to work properly